# How to optimize query with big OFFSET in mysql InnoDB?

Tags: mysql

My `user` table have ~ 1300000 records. If I query with a small OFFSET like :

```
SELECT u.id, ud.first_name, ud.last_name 
FROM user u LEFT JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id 
WHERE ud.first_name LIKE 'First Name%' OR ud.last_name LIKE 'First Name%' ORDER BY u.id 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

It's fast. But if I query with a big OFFSET like:

```
SELECT u.id, ud.first_name, ud.last_name 
FROM user u LEFT JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id 
WHERE ud.first_name LIKE 'First Name%' OR ud.last_name LIKE 'First Name%' ORDER BY u.id 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 1336040
```

It's slow.
I think the problem is not at WHERE or ORDER BY because I created index on them. I think when use a big OFFSET, DB have to scan table from the head until see offset needed => so it's slow ?

The explain query :

```
1   |SIMPLE |ud |range  |UNIQ_4B5464AEA76ED395,first_name_idx,last_name_idx |UNIQ_4B5464AEA76ED395  |5  |NULL   |711700 |Using index condition; Using where
1   |SIMPLE |u  |eq_ref |PRIMARY    |PRIMARY    |4  |trueprofile_dev.ud.user_id |1  |Using index
```

Comment: Can you explain your query. According your query, I guess mysql will use temp table on disk to store join results, and then lookup temp table by offset. For limit and offset problem, [late row lookups](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/) maybe help,

Comment: *`FROM user u LEFT JOIN user_detail ud ON u.id = ud.user_id`* 1) Remove LEFT - anycase WHERE makes it INNER. 2) Does only one `user_detail` row matches to each `user` row? PS. Big OFFSET is always slow. If approximate selection is not safe use pre-calculated posession number.